# remove substring in a string without using regex (cannot use replaceAll)

Tags: java, string, substring, replaceall

I need to remove some substrings in strings (in a large dataset). The substrings often contain special characters, like these: ., ^, /,... and replaceAll() would treat them as special characters for regex, such as a dot would match any character, which is not really what I want.

Is there other functions to do the "replace" without treating the first argument as regex?

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I BELEIVE you can escape regex special characters in Java with \, so \. would be treated as a regular .

Comment: you can jump special characters with "\" for example : \\^

Comment: @Kon Yes, but due to escaping in string literals two backslashes are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use String.replace(). It functions the same way, but it deals with escaping the special characters internally to avoid you having to worry about regex.

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Answer (score 2):

You can match literally. For instance, if we want to match "<.]}^", we can do:

```
Pattern pat=Pattern.compile("<.]}^", PATTERN.LITERAL");
```

and use that pattern.

You can also use backslashes to escape it. Note that the string literal itself needs backslashes, so escaping a single dot will take **two** backslashes, as follows:

```
Pattern pat=Pattern.compile("\\.");
```

First backslash is seen by compiler, and second backslash is taken as a backslash for the regex parser.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`String.replace(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29), not `replaceAll`.  `String.replace` doesn't treat its argument as a regex.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods named `replace` in the `String` class that perform replacement without treating their parameters as regular expressions.

One [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) method replaces one `char` with another `char`.

The other [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method replaces a `CharSequence` (usually a `String`) with another `CharSequence`.

Quoting the Javadocs from the second `replace` method:

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target
>   sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there other functions to do the "replace"

Yes, it is called [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) :) Main difference between it and [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is that it escapes regex special characters.

---

BTW if you want to escape regex's special characters in string you can

- use `yourString = Pattern.quote(yourString)`,
- surround it with `"\\Q"` and `"\\E"`,

to escape only some special characters you can

- use `"\\"` before them like `\\.`
- also most special characters can be escaped by surrounding them with `"["` and `"]"` like `[.]`.